# Prove $\frac{(x^2-5x+2)}{(x+1)} = x-6$ has no solutions using contradiction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I need help proving that this equation 
$$\frac{(x^2-5x+2)}{(x+1)} = x-6$$

has no solutions using contradiction.

I know that it has no solution because when you solve it you get 
$$\frac{8}{(x+1)} = 0$$

which is not true.

Comment: One way to make sure that there are no solutions is by graphing both the functions. First graph the function on the left side of the equality and then the one on the right. The number of points of intersection represent the number of solutions. Both these functions can be easily graphed by hand. But there is something incorrect in your question, because i graphed them and you get one solution (at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x=a be solution to $$\frac{(x^2-5x+2)}{(x+1)} = x-6$$

Then we have

$$\frac{(a^2-5a+2)}{(a+1)} = a-6$$

$${(a^2-5a+2)}=(a+1)(a-6)$$

$$a^2-5a+2 = a^2-5a-6$$

$$ 2=-6$$

This is a contradiction, so there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $x\neq -1$ we have:

$$x^2-5x+2 = (x-6)(x+1)+8\implies \frac{x^2-5x+2}{x+1} = x-6 + \frac 8{x+1}$$

and since $\frac 8{x+1}\neq 0$, your equation has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(x^2-5x+2)}{(x+1)} = x+6$$

$$(x^2-5x+2)=(x+1)(x+6)$$

$$x^2-5x+2=x^2+7x+6$$

$$ -12x =4$$

$$ x=-1/3$$

$ x=-1/3$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: I meant to say x-6 on the right side

Comment: For x-6 you get  2= -6 which has no solution.

Comment: I want to prove that the equation has no solution using contradiction. Solving the equation does not help me prove that the equation has no real solution.I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Let x=a be a solution then proceed my solution for x=a. You will get 2=-6 which is  a contradiction. So there is no solution if the right hand side is (x-6)